# Doxygen: link to C++ class member from page without writing class name

Tags: c++, doxygen

Let's say I have a class `Foo` with a member function `bar()`, documented with Doxygen:

**foo.h:**

```cpp
/// This is the Foo class.
class Foo
{
  /// Does something.
  void bar();
};
```

and a page in a separate file where I want to reference `bar()` (written in Markdown):

**notes.md:**

```
To do something, call bar().
```

I want "bar()" in the generated page to link to the documentation for the `bar()` function. I can make this happen by writing `Foo::bar()` instead, but I don't want it to be displayed as "Foo::bar()" in the page. What is a good way to make this happen?

Comment: TBH, and seeing the answer, I think `Foo::bar` is just better. It's more clear where you're referring to, and easier to write. Sure it might be cumbersome if you have to write 6 namespaces in, but that's likely a different issue altogether.

Comment: Yeah, I'm considering just keeping `Foo::`. The thing is, this documentation only covers a single class, so I think omitting the class name makes it more readable without making it harder to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've found so far is to use [`\ref`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdref) in notes.md:

```
To do something, call \ref Foo::bar() "bar()".
```

In my opinion, this is still a little messy, though. It also doesn't show a brief description of the function on mouseover, unlike auto-generated links.